# How draw a surface plot using matlplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have three variables:

```
gamma= [0.001, 0.0001]
c= [1, 10, 100, 1000]
f = [9.350473612990527483e-01, 8.848238482384823689e-01, 9.769335142469470767e-01, 8.534599728629578275e-01, 9.198369565217391353e-01, 8.953804347826085364e-01, 9.713506139154161056e-01, 9.836065573770491621e-01]
```

My question is how can I draw a surface plot using the above variables?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots

Comment: What is your X, Y and Z? You have 2 gamma points, 4 c points and 10 f points. I don't see any relation between them

Comment: I had run model using all combination of 2 parameter c and gamma and get output f . Now i want to plot f with respect to c and gamma.

Comment: The problem is that you have 2 gamma and 4 c points. So a total 4x2 = 8 pairs of gamma and c. So for each you will have one f value. So total you should have 8 f-values. But your data has 10 f values. Do you see what I am trying to explain?

Comment: Yes, F also have 8 values

Comment: Check my answer below. Let me know if something is unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is the solution using your `gamma`, `c` and `f` values although the surface looks a bit strange but that's due to your data. Please check the order of data. I assumed it to be `np.meshgrid(gamma, c)` but it could very well be `np.meshgrid(c, gamma)`. You need to verify that

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

gamma= np.array([0.001, 0.0001])
c= np.array([1, 10, 100, 1000])
X, Y = np.meshgrid(gamma, c)
f = np.array([9.350473612990527483e-01, 8.848238482384823689e-01, 9.769335142469470767e-01, 8.534599728629578275e-01, 9.198369565217391353e-01, 8.953804347826085364e-01, 9.713506139154161056e-01, 9.836065573770491621e-01])
Z = f.reshape(X.shape)

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
```

**Output**

[image]